# Problema con SSL stream en iphone

Tags: html, ssl, certificado-ssl, stream, radio

Resulta que tengo una webblog de radio, la cuál hasta hace unos días antes del apagón cibernético funcionaba tanto en windows, android y iOS. Luego de eso dejó de sonar la radio en iOS. Pensé que era la etiqueta audio la que fallaba pero descubrí que ese no es el problema. El problema es que mi stream está en https la url, se me dio por quitarle la s y dejarlo en http, y la radio empezó a escucharse nuevamente en iphone. Pero el problema es que al no tener https dejó de ser segura mi web. Cuál es la solución a este drama?

Comment: Hola, pudiste resolver tu problema? Si es así podrías contar mínimamente como lograste solucionarlo?. Saludos

Comment: Hola como estas? aún no pude solucionar, pero lo curioso es que en algunos iphone funciona, sin haber hecho nada y en otros modelos no.

Comment: Si podés agrega en la pregunta los datos del certificado SSL y además en que versión de iPhone y IOS está pasando.